# Object scope and lifetime in a for loop

Tags: c++, scope, object-lifetime

Suppose I have the following code.

```
vector<Cat> v; \\Cat is a class
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Cat cat1;
    if (someFunction(i))
    {
        cat1.setName("Whiskers");
        v.push_back(whiskers) ;
    }
}
```

My question is, in a for loop, does the object cat1 go out of scope while executing `0 to 4`? That is will the destructor get called 5 times here or just once?

Comment: I guess you could have found an answer elsewhere without asking, though

Comment: Why not just put some `cout` in the constructors/destructors? An instance answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor and destructor are called 5 times, right.

Because control flow crosses 5 times the initialization of `cat`, and 5 times the end of its scope (the closing '}' of loop block).

Actually, what you see in the outermost brace is actually one composite statement repeated while the loop condition (i < 5) is true.

Comment: So in essence, a for loop is actually exiting at each i, then reentering the brackets?

Comment: What about copy / move constructor in push_back()? It is called 5 times as well

Comment: copy constructor in push_back of course called as frequently as push_back itself, 5 times